# Autoadjusting sum cell range in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to make an auto adjustment for the sum value in Excel.

I need to calculate the percentage of hours based on the range between columns corresponding to the given week.
It can be 5 days, but for the first and the last week, it can be less than 5 days. However, some first weeks are empty because just the weekend occurs at the beginning of the month.

As you can see, my initial formula is fixed and applies to the situation, when the first day of the month is Friday.
[image]
After changes in the month, everything is shifted.

I tried to use the INDIRECT function:

https://www.lifewire.com/excel-sum-indirect-dynamic-range-formula-3124100

Next extracted the column letters
set the condition, which throws 0 when the column corresponds to the weekend
and applied to the following equation:

```
   =(SUM(INDIRECT(&L2:N2&5:&P2:R2&5))/(7.5-AT5)*100%)
```

which unfortunately didn't work

[image]

How to make this range dynamic?

UPDATE:

I tried this, but it didn't work either:

```
  =(SUM(INDIRECT(&P1&"5:"&P2&5))/(7.5-AT5)*100%)
```

EDIT:

```
  =(SUM(INDIRECT(Q1&5&":"&P2&5)))/(7.5-AT5)*100%
```

Now the formula is fine, but throws #REF despite correct values in the cell. What might be the reason behind it?

Comment: You can reference the Date row and ensure the dates are within the designated week and are weekdays.  Probably using either `SUMIFS` or `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: I don't know how to do it. SUMIF won't work in my case at all. I need something that will allow me to make the sum range shifted month by month.

Comment: I did not recommend `SUMIF`. And I am not going to copy your data manually to test any formula. Why did you choose to post a screenshot instead of text data that could be copy/pasted? [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: With regard to your most recent edit, your second screenshot shows `Q1` is blank; `P2` contains `P`, so your string `Q1&5&":"&P2&5` becomes `5:P5` which is not a valid address and will result in an error.